# How to ignore Ctrl-C events in flex that do not change a textbox contents?

Tags: apache-flex, textbox, copy-paste, textinput, flex-spark

Currently, it seems that every time Ctrl-C is pressed within a textbox to copy its content, the textbox receives an Event.CHANGE, and thus our application decides that a change was made in the text box and enables the "apply changes" button, although no changes were made, and all the user wanted was to copy the textbox contents.
The textbox component we're using is spark.components.TextInput

On view initialization I register:

```
_view.hostNameTextBox.addEventListener(
    Event.CHANGE, onConnectionDat‌aChanged, false, 0, true
);
```

And the event listener function is:

```
private function onConnectionDataChanged(e:Event):void {
    _view.applyButton.enabled = true;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Show some code, please.  In your event handler for a keyboard event you should be able to check if "C" was selected and the control key was pressed; but Event.CHANGe is not a keyboard event, so you really need to explain what event you're listening for, and what type of component you're listening on.

Comment: On view initialization I register:           
_view.hostNameTextBox.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.CHANGE,onConnectionDataChanged,false, 0, true);

And the event listener function is:
       
private function onConnectionDataChanged(e:Event):void {
_view.applyButton.enabled = true;
}

Comment: Edit your post and add the code to the post; please.  Be sure to highlight and click the "Curly Bracket" button on the question editing box.  that'll make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slight variation of @Sunil D.'s answer: use the `operation` property of the event to determine whether the current operation was a copy operation or another one:

```
private function inputChangeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
    var operation:IOperation = event.operation;
    if (operation is CopyOperation) trace("Ctrl+C was pressed");
    if (operation is InsertTextOperation) trace("New text was inserted");
    if (operation is DeleteTextOperation) trace("Some text was deleted");
}
```

This approach will also fix your issue with multiple TextInputs: only one event handler required instead of many.

Comment: Good idea! ... There are actually some other operations that could signify an edit was made (for example: `PasteOperation`, `CutOperation`, and `UndoOperation`)

Answer (score 0):

The Spark `TextInput` dispatches a [TextOperationEvent.CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/TextOperationEvent.html) event on every keystroke that you make.

However, unlike the [KeyboardEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html) that Flextras is referring to, this event does not tell you which keys were pressed. Instead the event has an [operation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/TextOperationEvent.html#operation) property which is a [FlowOperation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/operations/FlowOperation.html) that describes the change.

But don't bother with that. Since the change event will get dispatched on every keystroke, compare the value of the `TextInput` with the the value from the previous change event.

```
private var lastTextInputValue:String = "";

private function inputChangeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (textInput.text == lastTextInputValue)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    lastTextInputValue = textInput.text;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but if there's no way to avoid it, I'll try adding it (the problem that it's for 4 different fields, so the code can become a bit ugly...)

Comment: Another problem is that I use the same listener for a few different fields (hostname, username, etc...), so now I'll have to separate it to a few listeners...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

            protected function inPutText_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ctrlCPressed)
                {
                    clickBtn.enabled = false;
                    ctrlCPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    clickBtn.enabled = true;
                }
            }

            private var ctrlCPressed:Boolean = false;
            protected function inPutText_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(event.ctrlKey == true && event.keyCode == Keyboard.C)
                    ctrlCPressed = true;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:TextInput id="inPutText" change="inPutText_changeHandler(event)" text="Mahesh Parate"
                 keyDown="inPutText_keyDownHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="clickBtn" label="Click" enabled="false"/>
</s:Application>
```

The TextInput component contains two listeners, one for the TextInput.CHANGE event and one for the KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN. The keyDown listener will detect whether CTRL+C and set a flag. When the CHANGE event is handled, that listener will check whether the flag for CTRL+C is true or not and take the appropriate actions. If CTRL+C was pressed, the code will enable the button. If not, the button will be disabled and the flag reset to false.